# How to add the same column twice and force it to show another value?

Tags: sql, teradata

I wonder if there are any sensible ways to rewrite the following query so it does show the  'MY_LOAD_STATUS' twice in one row along with 'MY_LOAD_TIMESTAMP' so I can then count the real time of load execution by adding another column which will subtract MIN(MY_LOAD_TIMESTAMP) from MAX(MY_LOAD_TIMESTAMP)?

My current Select Statement is as follows:

```
SELECT MY_LOAD_DETAILS_ID,
        MY_LOAD_ID,
        MY_LOAD_SOURCE_SYSTEM,
        CAST(CAST(MY_LOAD_TIMESTAMP AS CHAR(19)) AS TIMESTAMP(0)),
        CAST(CAST(MY_LOAD_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT 'dd/mm/yyyyBhh:mi:SS.s(6)') AS DATE) AS "START DATE",
        CAST(CAST(MY_LOAD_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT 'dd/mm/yyyyBhh:mi:SS.s(6)') AS TIME) AS "START TIME ",
        MY_LOAD_STATUS,
        MY_LOAD_WORKFLOW_NAME
    FROM MY_PROD_DB.MY_LOAD_DETAILS
    WHERE MY_LOAD_ID='869230' 
    order by MY_LOAD_DETAILS_ID DESC;
```

The Output is as follows:

```
 MY_LOAD_DETAILS_ID     MY_LOAD_ID   MY_LOAD_SOURCE_SYSTEM    MY_LOAD_TIMESTAMP     START DATE     START TIME       MY_LOAD_STATUS      MY_LOAD_WORKFLOW_NAME

    5558                869230             SSS              2020-02-04 14:46:32   2020-02-04   14:46:32.000000     SUCCEEDED          wf_RRR_LOAD_FROM_SSS
  5557                869230             SSS              2020-02-04 14:44:03   2020-02-04   14:44:03.000000      STARTED           wf_RRR_LOAD_FROM_SSS
```

I would like it to be something like this:

```
MY_LOAD_ID   MY_LOAD_SOURCE_SYSTEM    MY_LOAD_TIMESTAMP (for Started)  MY_LOAD_TIMESTAMP (for Succeeded)   START DATE     START TIME       MY_LOAD_STATUS (for Started)  MY_LOAD_STATUS (for Succeeded)    MY_LOAD_WORKFLOW_NAME  MY_LOAD_TIMESTAMP (for Succeeded)-MY_LOAD_TIMESTAMP (for Started)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Andy

Comment: Will it always be exactly two rows?

Comment: I think there's a much better way of doing this by using window functions. Can you add the expected result clearly?

Comment: Seems like conditional aggregation. GROUP BY MY_LOAD_ID and whatever else makes sense, simple MIN/MAX for things that should match but are not part of GROUP BY, `MIN/MAX(CASE WHEN  MY_LOAD_STATUS = *one status* THEN *column name* END) as *column_for_status*` for TIMESTAMP and any other thing where you want a column from each status.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want aggregation?

```
SELECT MY_LOAD_DETAILS_ID, MY_LOAD_ID, MY_LOAD_SOURCE_SYSTEM,
       MIN(MY_LOAD_TIMESTAMP) as Start_date,
       MIN(MY_LOAD_TIMESTAMP) as Stop_date,
       MY_LOAD_STATUS,
       MY_LOAD_WORKFLOW_NAME
FROM MY_PROD_DB.MY_LOAD_DETAILS
WHERE MY_LOAD_ID = '869230' 
GROUP BY MY_LOAD_DETAILS_ID, MY_LOAD_ID, MY_LOAD_SOURCE_SYSTEM, MY_LOAD_STATUS, MY_LOAD_WORKFLOW_NAME
order by MY_LOAD_DETAILS_ID DESC;
```